# Meteor SEO and google bot

Tags: meteor, web-crawler, google-search-console, googlebot

I added `spiderable` package to my app.

When I load my pages with `?_escaped_fragment_=` it renders my page correctly, like it is a static one. But when I try to render it with 'Fetch as Google bot' using Webmaster tools and ask for a version without this query parameter, Google shows a blank page with some basic meteor scripts included. Not sure if it's the expected behavior or an issue with my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behavior.

Use tools such as Screaming Frog Seo Spider to check if your Ajax Crawling Protocol is ok.